# PyDev Python Builder lowercase L in string

Tags: pydev

I just installed the latest Eclipse Neon, and latest PyDev on that. When opening a python file using the "Python Editor" provided, all lowercase "L"s are automatically displayed as uppercase whenever enclosed in quotes.

Opening the same file in another editor shows all L's as lowercase, so the issue in the Python Editor is purely visual, but it's certainly odd. I've tried turning off code completion and code analysis and it didn't help.

Has anyone else seen this weirdness and found a reason / fix?

Comment: Haven't seen that... can you post a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: https://snag.gy/gnXhVM.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot, I'd say the issue isn't on the editor, but on the font you're using (the main difference from one case to the other is that by default, PyDev strings are italic and for some reason the font you've chosen shows lowercase `l` very close to `L` when italic -- although I think that the actual uppercase `L` is probably different from the lowercase `l` when italic too).

As for a solution, you can either not show the font as italic (in **Preferences > PyDev > Editor > uncheck 'Italic' for Unicode and Bytes**) or change the font you're using (in **Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Text Fond** and **Text Editor Block Selection Font**).